# Sorting a List in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

```
public class BatchProcess
    {
        public string process { get; set; }
        public DateTime runtime { get; set; }
        public bool running { get; set; }
    }
```

So I have a list of these guys - `List<BatchProcess> list`.

How would I sort based one each of those columns? I've heard I can do it with LINQ but I'm so bad with LINQ. How would that look?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could sort by runtime, for example, via:

```
var orderedByRuntime = list.OrderBy(p => p.runtime);
```

If you wanted to sort by "process" in descending order, you can use:

```
var orderedByProcessDesc = list.OrderByDecending(p => p.process);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of using LINQ (lambda syntax) to create a list that's sorted by `process`.

```
var listByProcess = list.OrderBy(bp => bp.process);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use OrderBy:

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(p => p.runtime).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort by all of them, as it seems this is what you are asking you can just do the following

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(p => p.process).ThenBy(r => r.runtime);
```